# Paypal rest api express checkout with no shipping field (WebProfile handling)

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I'm using Paypal rest api to make payment
the workflow is:

1. Create payment
2. Redirect to approval Url
3. User approved (return back to my site)
4. Execute payment

But there's one thing that I don't want users re-filling shipping address again because it was filled in my website.
So I change the workflow to:

1. Create web profile (set no shipping field)
2. Get web profile ID
3. Create payment with experienceProfileId given
4. Redirect to approval Url
5. User approved (return back to my site)
6. Execute payment

But I found this will create a lots WebProfile every time user request payment.

I think it is crazy to do:

- create and delete it later again and again
- attempt listing WebProfiles and check which is the one I want to use every time while creating payment
- store experienceProfileId as a constant

What is the best practice for handling WebProfile or does there any solution just hiding shipping address while user approving payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the answer regarding this "WebProfile". As a fact, I dont know what exactly "WebProfile" does or is.

I worked on the same Workflow these days. As you wrote I needed to predefine some address. For me it was obvious, that I have to do the database-stuff on my Website. Then I exactly define the order, shipping_address, etc. and send the users to Paypal.

If you predefine the `new ShippingAddress()` to your ´new ItemList()´ by 
$itemlist->setShippingAddress($shippingaddress) the user cannot change it within the Process.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPmRh.png

Maybe this helps you a little.